# Reading chinese double byte chars from iSeries DataReader

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-midrange, double-byte

I am using IBM iSeries .NET datareader to get data from the AS400.

1) What do I need to do in the AS400 side to send double byte chars
2) Will the IBM iSeries preserve double byte chars?  All I get is an empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Make sure your connection is set to use UTF-8.

2) The IBM i is certainly capable of storing double-byte data, it just depends on how the Physical File (table) was created. You can either execute `DSPFD LIBRARY/FILE` from a 5250 session and search for `DBCS capable` - you will see a `Yes` or `No` that indicates if the table is capable of storing double-byte characters. Of if you want to use SQL to find out you can query the SYSIBM database:

```
SELECT * FROM SYSIBM.SQLCOLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEM = 'MYLIB' AND TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLE'
```

You'll want to look for the `TYPE_NAME` column to see the data type. If it's `VARGRAPHIC` then it is capable of storing double-byte characters.

Comment: SO all I need to do in the .net side is to set the connection to UTF-8? will the datareader show it as a string?

Comment: @magic-c0d3r - I don't know anything about .NET, I'm an IBM i guy :-) But if you want to transfer multi-byte character data between systems the connection should use UTF-8.